# In below code I wanted to run honk() method last. But in the output honk() method runs first. Why

Tags: php

```
<?php 
        class Vehicle{
            protected $brand;

            function __construct($brand){
                $this->setBrand($brand);
            }
            function setBrand($brand){
                $this->brand=$brand;
            }

            function getBrand(){
                return $this->brand;
            }

            function honk(){
                echo "Beep Beep Beep...";
            }
        }

        class Car extends Vehicle{
            private $modelName;

            function setModelName($modelName){
                $this->modelName=$modelName;
            }

            function getModelName(){
                return $this->modelName;
            }
        }

        $carObject = new Car("Lamborghini");
        echo "</br>Car brand is ".$carObject->getBrand()."<br>";
        $carObject->setModelName("Aventador");
        echo "Car model is ".$carObject->getModelName()."<br>";

        echo($carObject->getBrand()." ".$carObject->getModelName()." is ".$carObject->honk());

    ?>
```

I added this function to subclass. but i do not understand that function too.

```
function honk(){
    parent::honk();
}
```

The output that i want is: Lamborghini Aventador is Beep Beep Beep...
but i am getting Beep Beep Beep...Lamborghini Aventador is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```php
echo($carObject->getBrand()." ".$carObject->getModelName()." is ".$carObject->honk());
```

The method calls are evaluated one after:

1. `$carObject->getBrand()` is called, **returning** the string `Lamborghini`.
2. `$carObject->getModelName()` is called, **returning** the string `Aventador`.
3. `$carObject->honk()` is called, **echoing** the string `Beep Beep Beep...` to the output. It does not **return** anything.
4. All the strings in previous steps are inserted and echoed to the output:

   ```php
   echo('Lamborghini'." ".'Aventador'." is ".'');
   ```

   Thus leading to `Beep Beep Beep...Lamborghini Aventador is`.

You may have meant to `return` in `honk()`:

```php
function honk(){
  return "Beep Beep Beep...";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function honk(){
  echo "Beep Beep Beep...";
}
```

Your honk `echo` runs first and then the last echo runs. Perhaps you need to `return` the message instead of `echo`?